# I can't connect socket io on my flutter app

Tags: express, dart, socket.io

I use socket-io-client: 2.0.1 and node server socket io: 4.4.1

but I have got the bellow error

"WebSocketException: Connection to url was not upgraded to websocket"

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you in advance.

my code is :

express node server side code

const io = socketio(server, {
cors: {
origin: "*",
methods: ["GET", "POST"]
},
transports: ['websocket']
});

flutter app client code

IO.Socket socket = IO.io(API_HOST, <String, dynamic>{
'transports': ['websocket', 'pooling'],
'autoConnect': false,
});
socket.connect();
socket.onError((data) => {print("$data")});

Comment: you're using a modern browser that supports web sockets I assume, and you're probably running localhost on HTTP not HTTPS?  Maybe check the compiled client code to see  value API_HOST, etc..

Comment: thanks for your advice.
My express server is on https, but I don't know why it is on http on my local.
you can check  www.aslaa.mn